# Post json object with iron-ajax as application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: javascript, json, spring-mvc, polymer

in my Polymer-based application I would like to use the fancy JavaScript model binding to input elements.

The POST of the model to my Spring controller however I would like to perform as classic formdata, so that I can take advantage of Spring SessionAttributes.

I set up `iron-ajax` like this:

```
<iron-ajax id="saveMailing"
    method="POST"
    url="/api/mailing"
    content-type="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    on-response="mailingSaved">
</iron-ajax>
```

I have a JavaScript method which on button click executes the request:

```
saveDraft: function() {
    this.$.saveMailing.body = this.mailing;
    this.$.saveMailing.generateRequest();
}
```

`this.mailing` is a JSON-object. It's *not* FormData().

The result is that I get a JavaScript error "Cannot read property toString of null", in iron-request.html:421

Is it possible at all to do what I want ?  I mean passing `iron-ajax` a JSON-Object and expecting it to transform it to FormData. Or do I not use `iron-ajax` correctly ?

Comment: you haven't shown us where `this.mailing` comes from.its looking like iron-ajax thinks it is null

Comment: i've definitely used `iron-ajax` with a `new FormData()` style data set.  once you add the `this.mailing` definition above there's got to be just something silly or small that's escaping you.

Comment: this.mailing is a json-object, and it's not null.

Comment: And I believe the real question is: Can iron-ajax convert a JavaScript-Object to FormData() ?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're positive that `this.mailing` is not `null`, you need to stringify it first:

```
this.$.saveMailing.body = JSON.stringify(this.mailing);
```

Comment: I had already tried this, and re-tried it right now ... but it does not work neither.

Comment: I fact, it does the POST, but not with form-data, but with a JSON-String. So  JSON.stringify() works, but a conversion to form-data does not happen.

Comment: Are you using PHP on the server side?  I find myself having to use `$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);`.

Comment: I use a Spring Controller, so Java, with the ModelAttribute annotation which parses the form-data directly into an object.